# iis redirect/transfer from iis root

Tags: http, iis, redirect, module, handler

I would like to know if it's possible to transfer a request, using http module or http handler in IIS, something like this:

request: http://ip_addr/stb.xml   (/stb.xml would be an argument)

transfer: http://SomeApp/handler.ashx?arg=stb.xml

So the initial request only has the ip of the web server plus /stb.xml (it's a request made by an iphone app, which can only send requests in the format http://ip/arg_function/, which should be forwarded to an SetTopBox by an application server), there is no app name in request. Is it possible?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Simple! I solved it by deploying the app (which contains the http handler) in the root directory of iis, wwwroot.
The handler intercepts and processes all requests with some configurable path pattern.
Hope this helps.